# Java - How to programmatically download an attachment from a URL which opens a new tab?

Tags: java, http, download

I need to download an attachment from a `URL` (say `http://mywebsite.com`) programmatically using `Java`. The tricky part is that the above URL opens up a new tab/window `onload` from which the downloading actually starts.

E.g.

1. Open `http://mywebsite.com`
2. `http://mywebsite.com` loads and **opens up a new tab** to `http://mywebsite.com/attachments/someRandomFileName.pdf`

*Note the file name in step `2` (above) is randomly assigned so I cannot hit `http://mywebsite.com/attachments/someRandomFileName.pdf` directly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you extract the URL from the JavaScript code that is embedded in (or linked to from) the HTML you receive from `http://mywebsite/com`?

Comment: That launched URL must be delivered to the original page somehow, whether it's through a `setTimeout` or an Ajax call.  If it's not embedded in the page, you'll have to replicate a browser and execute necessary JavaScript code (or at least replicate the HTTP requests the page would make).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole point of randomly generated URLs is to prevent people to access content directly.

They probably want users to go through their web site to access the file. There are numerous ways to check that request is coming from a real user/browser. This includes executing javascript and/or flash. Random URLs are generated on server and at some point they will be sent to browser.

So basically, to download a file, you'd have to look at what their web site is doing, what kind of requests it is making and what replies it gets from servers. Then try to reverse engineer this to get directly to random URL representing the file.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I will try to reverse engineer the site (it's gonna be very tricky)